# Why are divisons of flipped digits almost always so whole?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

After playing with my calculator for a while I tried doing $\frac{9876543210}{0123456789}$ and it came out as $80.000000729$ which came really close to a whole number so I tried it for the first 16 number bases and I got this:

Base 2 - 2 ->In base 2:($\frac{10}{01}$)->In base 10: ($\frac{3}{1}$)

Base 3 - 4.2   ->In base 3:( $\frac{210}{012}$)   ->In base 10:($\frac{21}{5}$)

Base 4 - 8.444444444444445   ->In base 4:($\frac{3210}{0123}$)   ->In base 10:($\frac{228}{27}$)

Base 5 - 15.103092783505154   ->In base 5:($\frac{43210}{01234}$)   ->In base 10:($\frac{2930}{194}$)

Base 6 - 24.01608579088472  ->In base 6:($\frac{543210}{012345}$)   ->In base 10:($\frac{44790}{1865}$)

Base 7 - 35.00183606557377   ->In base 7:($\frac{6543210}{0123456}$)   ->In base 10:($\frac{800667}{22875}$)

Base 8 - 48.00016355570094   ->In base 8:($\frac{76543210}{01234567}$)   ->In base 10:($\frac{16434824}{342391}$)

Base 9 - 63.00001189405568   ->In base 9:($\frac{876543210}{012345678}$)   ->In base 10:($\frac{381367044}{6053444}$)

Base 10 - 80.000000729   ->In base 10:($\frac{9876543210}{0123456789}$)   ->In base 10:($\frac{9876543210}{123456789}$)

Base 11 - 99.00000003855433   ->In base 11:($\frac{A9876543210}{0123456789A}$)   ->In base 10:($\frac{282458553905}{2853116705}$)

Base 12 - 120.00000000179136   ->In base 12:($\frac{BA9876543210}{0123456789AB}$)   ->In base 10:($\frac{8842413667692}{73686780563}$)

Base 13 - 143.00000000007418   ->In base 13:($\frac{CBA9876543210}{0123456789ABC}$)   ->In base 10:($\frac{300771807240918}{2103299351334}$)

Base 14 - 168.00000000000276   ->In base 14:($\frac{DCBA9876543210}{0123456789ABCD}$)   ->In base 10:($\frac{11046255305880158}{65751519677857}$)

Base 15 - 195.00000000000009   ->In base 15:($\frac{EDCBA9876543210}{0123456789ABCDE}$)   ->In base 10:($\frac{435659737878916200}{2234152501943159}$)

Base 16 - 224   ->In base 16:($\frac{FEDCBA9876543210}{0123456789ABCDEF}$)   ->In base 10:($\frac{18364758544493064000}{81985529216486900}$)

This took me too long to make... Well anyways this thing seems to approach a whole number.

Another thing I noticed was that the answers were about Base n = $n^2-2n$ if you ignore the exception of base 2...

Can anyone give me some sort of explanation?

Comment: Try adding the numerator and denominator, and see if that gives you a clue.

Answer (score 2):

The denominator in base $b$ is very close to the first repeat of the fraction $\frac 1{(b-1)^2}$.  For example in base $10$ we have 
$$\frac 1{81}=0.012345679012345679\ldots$$
which differs from your denominator by excluding the $8$.  The pattern is general.  If you express $\frac 1{25_{10}}$ in base $6$ the repeat is $.01235_6$.  The denominator is then very close to $\frac {b^b}{(b-1)^2}$If you add $1$ to your fraction, the numerator becomes $b^b-1$ so your fraction is essentially $\frac {b^b-1}{\frac {b^b}{(b-1)^2}}-1=(b-1)^2-1$

Comment: Your fraction is actually $\dfrac{\dfrac{(b^2-2b)b^b-b}{(b-1)^2}}{\dfrac{b^b-b^2+b-1}{(b-1)^2}} = b^2-2b +\dfrac{b^4-3b^3+3b^2-3b}{b^b-b^2+b-1} $ so just over $b^2-2b=(b-1)^2-1$ for large $b$